# Problems with „Start Developing iOS Apps“-Guide after Upgrading to Swift 3: Rating Control not visible

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, interface-builder

With the release of *Swift 3.0* and *Xcode 8.0* I decided to have a look at a project I had built recently following *Apple’s* very own guide [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift) - you can download the sample project [here](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/Start-Dev-iOS-Apps-10.zip).

After converting to current *Swift* syntax and some minor adjustments to the project, the code compiles without errors and the app runs flawlessly except for the custom control defined in `RatingControl.swift` not being visible. Moving the view out of the stack view with *Interface Builder*  turns it visible but as soon as constraints being added it disappears again.

Is it a bug or does the code need further adjustments?

For the sake of completeness: Code was converted automatically, `Privacy Photo Library Usage Description` was added to `Info.plist`, forced unwrapping was removed in `saveMeals()` and `loadMeals()`, additional downcasting was added in `prepare(for:sender:)` located in `MealViewController.swift`.

Thank you in advance.

---

*Interface Builder*

[image: Screenshot: Interface Builder]

---

*RatingControl.swift*

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {
    // MARK: Properties

    var rating = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
    var spacing = 5
    var stars = 5

    // MARK: Initialization

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
        let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")

        for _ in 0..<5 {
            let button = UIButton()

            button.setImage(emptyStarImage, for: UIControlState())
            button.setImage(filledStarImage, for: .selected)
            button.setImage(filledStarImage, for: [.highlighted, .selected])

            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)
            ratingButtons += [button]
            addSubview(button)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Set the button's width and height to a square the size of the frame's height.
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)

        // Offset each button's origin by the length of the button plus spacing.
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
            buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (buttonSize + spacing))
            button.frame = buttonFrame
        }
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        let width = (buttonSize + spacing) * stars

        return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action

    func ratingButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        rating = ratingButtons.index(of: button)! + 1

        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
            // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button should be selected.
            button.isSelected = index < rating
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a little long, but I'll try to give the short version: there is a new behavior in the latest Xcode when you convert your old storyboards to the template that uses an initial device size. When the controller hits `viewDidLoad`, the frames of the subviews of the controller's main view still didn't calculate their initial frames yet, and all have a size of 1000x1000. This throws off some UIs that were working fine until you converted them to IB in Xcode 8.0 - especially when you needed, for example, to know the height of a button to calculate its corner radius. In many cases, a simple call to `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before modifying these views solves the problem, but that's not the case on this project.

I am not going to elaborate more on this because, quite frankly, I'm still getting used to these issues - on my projects, I'm treating them case by case.

The project in question is using a combination of stack views / some AutoLayout / content mode, which causes a weird behavior: on the controller you referenced, the problem seemed to be that the container stack view didn't know the rating control's height.

I tried a few things: first, I added a height constraint of 44.0 to the rating control. This made it appear, but the width was wrong - it was matching the width of the stack view, and the rating control was aligned left instead of centered.

What ultimately worked was:

- Adding a container view in the stack view and setting its height to 44.0
- Making the rating control a subview of that container view
- Adding width and height constraints to the Rating control (240.0 x 44.0)
- Centering the ratings control horizontally and vertically on its superview

Something to notice: not setting a width constraint also caused a weird behavior - the rating control's width was crazy big for some reason.

I don't know if this is the ultimate answer to your question, but this seems to have done the trick. You can find the [project I edited here](https://github.com/al7/SOAnswer-FoodTracker), if this is helpful. I added background colors / border colors to the container views and rating control for better visualization.

Hope this helps.